# "конец XVIII - начало XX вв". или "конец XVIII - начало XX века"?

Tags: согласование

Есть название книги: "Национальная политика империи (30-е гг. XVIII - начало XX вв.)".
Прошу ответить на вопрос: правильно ли писать 30-е гг. XVIII - начало XX **вв.**, или надо: 30-е гг. XVIII - начало XX **века**.
Заранее благодарен за ответ с объяснениями.

Comment: В обозначении временного интервала используется тире: конец X — начало XX вв.; при круглых датах пробелы исключаются:  X—XX вв.

Comment: Добывать ТИРЕ из таблицы символов не обязательно: Alt + 0151.

Answer (score 1):

В текущем виде, правильно "ХХ века", иначе рассогласование в падежах. Правда, такая запись в научных работах по истории редка. Обычно формулируют "кон. Х - нач. ХХ вв." (без скобок), что читается как *конц**а** Х - начал**а** ХХ век**ов**.*

Да и как историку, хоть и другой специализации, мне непонятна датировка в названии. К чему ее завуалировать, если и верхняя и нижняя границы вполне конкретные года (1722-1917)? Даже если первые 8 лет империи по каким-то причинам не рассматриваются, то все 1730-е правила исключительно Анна  Иоановна, что опять-таки дает конкретную дату начала ее правления.

Comment: А XVIII остаётся без своего "века"?