# Сам черт ему не брат

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Происхождение выражения "сам черт ему не брат" (= бесшабашный человек) не совсем ясно. В чем здесь смысл : если бы черт "был братом" кому-то, неужели было бы лучше?

Comment: Я бы ещё метку «этимология» добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю , что в истолковании значения следует сделать акцент в сторону **неуправляемости** и **выходу из-под контроля** того сообщества или социальной группы , к которой сам же и принадлежит , - при том что это сообщество или социальная группа имеет довольно сомнительную репутацию . Тут очень ценно *продолжение* *фразы* , которое привёл **@Tagirix** <<... *и свинья не сестра*>> . То есть , коллектив , члены которого подобны *чертям* и *свиньям*  , - но ОН и их превзошёл в своей лихости и невоспитанности , став неуправляемым даже с их стороны .

Comment: Я вообще-то мальчик. =/

Comment: Кажется, это верное направление! "Не брат черту, а гораздо хуже".

Comment: @ Tagirix . Я прошу прощения , но Дерзкий Granium в комменте на ваш ответ обратился к Вам , как к даме : "... ты сама-то поняла , что написала ??" . Я посчитал , что он достаточно хорошо знаком с Вами , чтобы конкретизировать пол . Вношу исправление в свой ответ .

Comment: »Автора статеечки хочется спросить : ты сама-то поняла, что написала?? 

Я здесь не фигурирую вообще. :)

Comment: @ Tagirix . Признаю свою вину за невнимательность . А также приглашаю Вас ознакомиться с ещё одним моим ОТВЕТОМ на этот ВОПРОС . СМ. ниже .

Answer (score 1):

Изложу свою версию, которая пересекается с ответом @следопыт.

Вспомним цитату из гоголевской "Ночи перед Рождеством" :

> Толстый Пацюк поднял голову и снова начал
> хлебать галушки.
> — Ты, говорят, не во гнев будь сказано... —
> сказал, собираясь с духом, кузнец, — я веду об
> этом речь не для того, чтобы тебе нанесть какую
> обиду, — **приходишься немного сродни черту.**

Знахари и колдуны считались родней нечистой силе и их побаивались. Однако и у таких особых людей были свои правила и "кодекс поведения". Служишь кому-то, богу или черту, знай свое место и чин, как говорится. Те, кто не обращал внимания ни на какие запреты, тоже встречались, хотя и редко. В гугл-книгах нашлось самое раннее упоминание сабжа, еще 18 столетия :

> Комическая опера "Мельник – колдун, обманщик и сват", Александр Аблесимов , 1779
>
> А н к у д и н.
> Ну смотри ж, жена, чтоб слезы
> Ты не стала утирать.
> (Говорит)             Я   с   тобою,   лебедь   моя,   справлюсь,  дай-ка  мне  только приобострожиться, а то нет, ты востра очень, и что ты думаешь дворянского-та отродья, **так тебе и черт не брат!**

Человек, не признающий ничьих авторитетов, добрых или злых, стоял уж совсем наособицу в мнении людей. Усовестить или приструнить такого было невозможно : он ни во что не верил!

Comment: . Тут у меня , с некоторым опозданием , возникла одна предположительная версия относительно происхождения этого фразеологизма . И я поместил ещё один ответ на ВОПРОС . Приглашая ознакомиться , см. ниже .

Answer (score 0):

***Сам черт ему не брат***

***часто шутл.***

***о независимом, отважном, способном на риск человеке.***
Есть две версии происхождения этого оборота:

> 1. Выражение связано с представлением о нечистой силе как о родне или семейном близком друге, соседе и т. д. В живой речи оборот имеет шутливое продолжение — и свинья не сестра. Причисление домовых, леших и т. п. к “своим” было обусловлено суеверным убеждением, что “черт своих не берет”. Отсюда и многочисленные способы задабривания домовых и леших.
> 2. Возможно, оборот связан с французским фразеологизмом “король ему не брат”. Фразеологизм этот является следствием того, что в Средние века король Франции давал высшим лицам — своим приближенным — титул кузена. Не имевшие такого титула проявляли большую независимость от короля.

[См. Фразеологический словарь.](http://frazeolog_ru.academic.ru/526/%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82,__%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC_%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82)

Comment: По указанной вами ссылке написана полная, хотя и наукообразная ерунда. Автора статеечки хочется спросить :  ты сама-то поняла, что написала??

Comment: Вы поменяли ссылку и вторая версия достаточно интересна (первая содержит явное противоречие, см. вопрос). Но выражение "сам черт не брат" появилось в русском языке ~ в конце 20-х, начале 30-х гг 19 века. Средневековые французские короли далековато будут.

Comment: Ссылку менял, если что, не я.

Comment: Хорошо, заметано)

Comment: «в конце 20-х, начале 30-х гг 19 века»... Это было в июне: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416392/конец-xviii-начало-xx-вв-или-конец-xviii-начало-xx-века

Answer (score 0):

Тут у меня возникла одна интересная версия происхождения фразеологизма <<САМ ЧЁРТ НЕ БРАТ , И СВИНЬЯ НЕ СЕСТРА>> . На эту версию меня натолкнула одна очень интересная книжка , вспомнившаяся мне , к сожалению , с некоторым опозданием , - **Вадим Бурлак . "Предания разбойничьих дорог"** . Поэтому я добавляю ещё один ОТВЕТ на этот ВОПРОС .  Автор Вадим Бурлак - киевский исследователь , собирающий легенды и народные предания . Из печати вышли несколько его работ по этой тематике ; "Предания разбойничьих дорог" одна из них . В главе 4. , повествующей о похождениях знаменитого московского бандита XVIII века Ваньки Каина , есть один интересный эпизод , относящийся к самому началу его преступной биографии . Причем , насколько можно понять автора , рассказ об этом эпизоде представляет из себя *прямую цитату из архивных материалов сыскного дела Ваньки Каина* . А , именно : когда Ванька Каин , вместе с сообщником по прозвищу Камчатка покидал дом  обворованного им богатого московского купца ("гостя") , то Камчатка написал на воротах , - "Пей воду , как гусь , ешь хлеб , как **свинья** , а работай **чёрт** , а не я !"  Обратим внимание , что здесь тоже <<ЧЁРТ>> и <<СВИНЬЯ>> употребляются в одной связке . Лично , у меня , возникает предположение , что существовало какое-то стародавнее народное поверье , циркулировавшее в люмпен-среде , содержание которого уже , к сожалению , начисто утрачено , и в котором фигурировали <<ЧЁРТ>> и <<СВИНЬЯ>> . Поэтому ,  дерзкая надпись на воротах , сделанная московским ворюгой в XVIII столетии , и более современный фразеологизм <<САМ ЧЁРТ НЕ БРАТ , И СВИНЬЯ НЕ СЕСТРА>> суть разные  перепевы этого утраченного стародавнего поверья или сказочки про чёрта , свинью и , наверное , ещё гуся . Ну , а поскольку это поверье утрачено , то докопаться до полной истины уже практически невозможно . Можно только высказывать предположительные гипотезы , как это делаю я сейчас .                                              ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  С книгой Вадима Бурлака вы можете ознакомиться , найдя её по поисковику в интернете . Существует и аудиоверсия "Преданий ..." , интернет-ссылку на скачивание аудиоверсии помещаю : [В.Бурлак . Предания разбойничьих дорог.](http://audio-knigki.ru/istoriya/9139-burlak-vadim-predaniya-razboynichih-dorog.html) . Приятного вам прослушивания !